# Adding ID to LI Javascript

Tags: javascript

So I have this following code set up to create an `li` element when someone inputs something into a box. I also want the `li` element to contain a unique ID which will begin with `list-Item0` and go to `list-Item1`, etc with every `li` created when someone types into the box and adds the item.

Any idea how I would go about doing this? I don't know what JQuery is as I am a complete beginner so am looking for something extremely basic which I can implement in this code.

Here's what I have so far:

```
function addItemFunction() {
    document.getElementById("itemList").innerHTML=document.getElementById("itemList").innerHTML + '<li>' + addNewBox.value + '</li>';  
}
```

Comment: @DeanRather—no, don't do that. Much better for the OP to learn plain JS, then make his/her own decision about which library (if any) best suits their needs for a particular purpose.

Answer (score 6):

Simply keep a counter for the ID outside your function, create an `<li>` element, set the ID and content, increment the counter and append the element to your `itemList`.

```
var listItemCounter = 0;        

function addItemFunction() {
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.id = 'list-Item' + listItemCounter++;
    li.innerHTML = addNewBox.value;

    document.getElementById('itemList').appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: I was just making a JS Fiddle for you to mess with when Phil posted this.  Here ya go: https://jsfiddle.net/0fn8wf65/

Answer (score 2):

As an extension to Phil's answer, you can avoid the global counter by keeping it in a closure:

```
var addItemFunction = function () {
    var listItemCounter = 0;        

    return function () {
        var li = document.createElement('li');
        li.id = 'list-Item' + listItemCounter++;
        li.innerHTML = addNewBox.value;

        document.getElementById('itemList').appendChild(li);
    };
}());
```

Comment: The counter in my answer isn't necessarily *global*, it's just outside the function (as it is in this answer).